# Is there any way to use composition to alter the CSS of an web-component with a shadow dom?

Tags: shadow-dom, web-frontend, lit-element

my team lead has decided to use LitElement to create framework-agnostic web components, which makes sense, as we're creating a company-wide UI library that would be ideal to be used with Vue2, Vue3, React, Preact, and others.

However, I'm extremely worried about styling.  Right now with our current (Vue 2) based UI library, if one of our teams needs to override the internal styling of an element for whatever reason (usually edge cases), one of the things they can do is use CSS Composition in order to do exactly that.  Something like:

```
// in components/my-element.js
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render(){
    return html`
      <div class="stackui-my-element">
        <p class="paragraph">A paragraph</p>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

// in app/businessthing.js
import React from 'react';
import {css} from 'styled-components'
const customCSS = css`
  .this-thing {
    & .stackui-my-element .paragraph {
      border: 2px dotted pink;
    }
  }
`
export default (props) => <div class="this-thing"><my-element /></div>
```

As far as I can tell, the above code won't work ("My Paragraph" would not be surrounded with pink polka dots) because MyElement has its own shadow dom, and you can't reach in it from without to change the styles of the element.

Is there some sort of exception to the rule, or can you reach inside the shadow dom somehow?  Other than losing CSS encapsulation, what are the other effects of disabling the shadow dom?

Comment: Maybe [Inheriting style](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#inheriting-styles) or [Custom properties](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#configurable) ?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, when using Shadow DOM, style encapsulation would prevent users of the component from affecting the styling of the component's internals.

However, there are several ways to achieve what you want with different degrees of flexibility, all of them are part of how the Shadow DOM spec behaves and not Lit-specific, so, you could use this with Vanilla Web Components or components created with other libraries too.

Which of the following ways works better will depend on how strict you want to enforce styling rules for your component.

All the samples below will assume the internal DOM of the component looks like your sample

```
<div class="stackui-my-element">
  <p class="paragraph">A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

1. Use custom CSS properties (CSS variables)

This approach is good when you want to limit the customization to only specific parts.

For example, to allow for the user to only be able to change the border for the paragraph, you could use a CSS variable with a fallback for the border in the style for your component's shadow DOM like this:

```
.paragraph {
  border: var(--myel-paragraph-border, 1px solid black);
}
```

And then, users who wish to customize said border could just change the value for that CSS variable through inline styles or a class.

```
<style>
  .fancy-border {
    --myel-paragraph-border: 2px dotted pink;
  }
</style>
<my-element class="fancy-border"></my-element>
```

The biggest limitation of this approach is that you would need to add a CSS variable for every property you wish to allow to be customized.

However, this can be an advantage for some use cases (like say, strict design systems) because it will not allow users to customize anything you don't wish to customize.

2. Use Shadow Parts

Shadow parts are one of the newer parts of the shadow DOM spec but [browser support is pretty good by this point](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_part). They allow you to define arbitrary parts of your component you wish to be fully customizable from outside the shadow DOM.

To use them, you need to add the `part` attribute to the HTML node you wish to define as the part.

```
<div class="stackui-my-element">
  <p part="paragraph" class="paragraph">A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And when using the component, add the `::part()` selector to the styles so that you can customize that specific part rather than the component host. It works pretty similar to how you would styles things such as a native input placeholder and so on.

```
<style>
  .fancy::part(paragraph) {
    /* you can do whatever you want here */
    border: 2px dotted pink;
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
  }
</style>
<my-element class="fancy"></my-element>
```

As you can see, shadow parts will allow you to override every style applied to the node, so, you must be careful when to use them as users might end up being able to customize things you don't want them too.

Final notes:

You could also achieve a similar thing using slots, but that might not be an easy change considering the contents of your question.

[Here's an article](https://dev.to/alangdm/the-quirks-of-shadow-dom-and-how-to-take-advantage-of-them-4cd1) in case you want more info on how styling Shadow DOM from outside the component works. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of that article.)

Comment: Would I be able to use ::part() to grab children?  That is... could I do  

`<div part="stackui-my-element" class="stackui-my-element">
    <p class="paragraph">A paragraph</p>
</div>`

And be able to style the paragraph via `.my-element::part(stackui-my-element) > p { border: 2px dotted pink; }`

Comment: I'd like to point out that in your Dev.to article, the first example you cite in your quiz is *EXACTLY* the behavior that I *don't* want.  I want to be able to have the Light DOM's styles override the Shadow DOM's styles if the Light DOM's styles have more CSS specificity.

Comment: @BrianBoyko I doubt shadow DOM is what you're looking for then. It's not meant to be used like that.

Comment: @rschristian Oh, I *KNOW* Shadow DOM isn't what I'm looking for.  It's what I'm being *made to use* by my team lead. I stated my objections and recommended an alternate solution, he overruled them.